# qt5 catch input from qtextedit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, stdin

I am working on a small application which is basically a serial terminal with some added stuff.

for the terminal window I use the `QTextEdit` widget and allready overload add and overload some methods. However since this is a serial terminal I don't want the input that the user is typing in the `QTextEdit` to actually end up there. Most serial communication channels echo back the input that is send to them and I would like to show this in the `QTextEdit` and not what the user inputs.

The ideal would be I could overload the way `QTextEdit` handles its input and I work from there.

I have looked online but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. Maybe I am using the wrong search terms

Comment: `typing in the QTextEdit to actually end up there` Then where ?

Comment: appended to a variable or list or whatever. Just so I can have freedom to do whatever I want with,

Comment: @RG337, so you want to use a `QTextEdit` as both input and output widgets in the same time? So use inputs "foo", but `QTextEdit` shows "foo goo" instead?

Comment: @vahancho Yes both input and output. Let's say the user has the widget in focus and types `hello`, this `hello` is not displayed in the `QTextEdit` but is stored in a variable. This then gets send via `pyserial` to some device. This Device wil echo back `hello` which then gets written to the `QTextEdit`.

Comment: @RG337, I see. I would get crazy with such use model. I think user should see what he/she inputs. You can use one text box for input and another one (label) for device response.

Comment: Would it not be quite inconvenient if the user didn't see what he is typing?

Comment: @vahancho This is how ALL serial terminals do it. This is because serial devices echo back what you write. So to the user it looks the same

Comment: @thuga serial devices echo back what you send to them most of the time. I send an `a` and I recieve an `a` back

Comment: Well you explained it differently. You said you type `hello`, store it in a variable, send it to some device and it will echo back `hello`. You didn't say you will send it character by character.

Comment: @thuga well serial devices have to, by design, send it character by character. What you probably meant is that it is buffered by newlines. But I assume once I have full control of how qt handles writing to `QTextEdit` I have no problems since that itself is not line buffered

Comment: What happens if you set it to read only mode and just listen for its keyevents? Could that work for you?

Comment: @thuga amazing, thank you! I didn't realize keyevent would be local to the widget in focus. Make it an answer so I can accept :). I am new to QT so I haven't figured out all of these things which may seem standard to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `QTextEdit` widget to [read-only](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#readOnly-prop) mode and then just listen for its key events. That way nothing will be displayed in the `QTextEdit` and you will be able to intercept the keys.

If you subclass `QTextEdit` and reimplement the `keyPressevent`, you might want to call the base class implementation inside it. Otherwise you might not get the functionalities that for example page-up/page-down keys provide.